# ADFS Passive Request = "There are no registered protocol handlers"

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, windows-server-2016

Im trying to configure `ADFS` to work as a `Claim Provider` (I suppose AD will be the `identity provider` in this case).

Just for simple testing, ive tried the following on `windows server 2016` machine:

1) Setup AD and domain = `t1.testdom` (Its working cause im actually able to login with the domain)

2) Setup DNS. Added a host (A) for adfs as `fs.t1.testdom`

3) selfsigned certificate (https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh848633):

```
powershell> New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "*.t1.testdom"
```

4) setup ADFS.

Server name set as `fs.t1.testdom`

service>authentication method is enabled as `form authentication`

5) Also fixed the SPN via powershell to make sure all needed SPNs are there and given to the right user account and that no duplicates are found

--

However, when I try to access the login page on browser via `https://fs.t1.testdom/adfs/ls` I get the error. The log on server manager says the following:

```
`There are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/ls to process the incoming request`
```

So is there a way to reach at least the login screen? So I can move on to the next error.

---

this is what I get on the `/ls` screen:

[image]

Comment: I followed this guide to setup:
https://www.virtuallyboring.com/how-to-setup-microsoft-active-directory-federation-services-adfs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the solution after a week of google, tries, server rebuilds etc!

(This guru answered it in a blink and no one knew it!
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28994182/ADFS-Passive-Request-There-are-no-registered-protocol-handlers.html)

The IdP-Initiated SSO page (https://fs.t1.testdom/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx). Note that if you are using Server 2016, this endpoint is **disabled by default** and you need to enable it first via the AD FS console or

```
Set-AdfsProperties -EnableIdPInitiatedSignonPage $true
```

--

My question is, if this endpoint is disabled, why isnt it listed in the endpoints section of ADFS Management console as such?!! It said `enabled` all along all this time over there. And this painful untraceable error msg in the log that doesnt make any sense! All windows does is create logs and logs and logs and yet this is the error log we get!

Answer (score 1):

1.If you want to check if ADFS is operational or not, you should access to the IDPInitiatedSignon page with URL: **https://<*ADFSExternalDNSName*>/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx**

as well as the metadata page with URL: **https://<*ADFSExternalDNSName*>/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml**

More details about this could be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn486821(v=ws.11).aspx).

2.That's not recommended to use the host name as the federation service name. A correct way is to create a DNS host(A) record as the federation service name, for example use sts.t1.testdom in your case.

Comment: yea thats what I did. created host(A) adfs.t1.testdom

Comment: I can open the federationmetadata.xml url as well as the `adfs/ls/`. But on the `/ls/` page it says error instead of showing the form

Comment: See updates above, ive added the image

Comment: What will you see if you use the URL https://fs.t1.testdom/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx If you can sign in successfully on this page then your ADFS should be operational.

Comment: Ive attached the image above in the original question of what I see on that page.

Comment: But I only saw the URL on your image is https://fs.t1.testdom/adfs/ls/, which is exactly not the one I provided to you. If I use the URL like yours, I will see the same error message in my working ADFS lab.

Comment: thanks for the reply. yea I tried all possible urls including the one you gave me.

Comment: when I put `IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx`, it says resource is not available. thats because under the `endpoints` page on ADFS management, the endpoint for saml is listed only upto `/ls/`

Comment: ADFS 4.0? Enabled? Refer: https://jorgequestforknowledge.wordpress.com/2014/10/24/enabling-idp-initiated-sign-on-in-adfs/

Comment: Also as I noted above, you should setup a new DNS host(A) record which is different from your ADFS server name. This record is used as the federation service name configured on the WAP&External DNS and this service name should match the SSL certificate's common name/SAN as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell you what can be the issue without logs or details configuration of your ADFS but in order to narrow down I suggest you:

1. Investigate the **IIS logs** to see if you get the HTTP request on destination to your ADFS
2. Investigate the **Event logs (section ADFS)**
3. Use the Dev tools from your browser or take an SAML trace using SAMLTracer (Firefox extension) to know if you have some HTTP error code.
4. Try to open connexion into your ADFS using for example : `telnet adfs.t1.testdom 443`
5. Try to enable Forms Authentication in your Intranet zone for the
   Global Authentication Policy.

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Point 5) already there.

Point 2) Thats how I found out the error saying "There are no registered protoco.."

Comment: I followed this guide https://www.virtuallyboring.com/how-to-setup-microsoft-active-directory-federation-services-adfs/, and the whole idea is to setup basic ADFS as a starting point. Once im done with the basics, I move to OAuth2.

Comment: My Scenario is to use AD as identity provider, and one of the websites I have *externally) as service provider. to ADFS plus oauth2.0 is needed.

Comment: There is no IIS