# Making an HTTP Request for an ADFS IP, Getting "There are no registered protocol handlers"

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, adfs, single-sign-on

I am trying to use the passive requester protocol defined in http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/v1.2/ws-federation.html

To do this, I am making the GET Request:

curl -X GET -k -i 'https://DOMAIN_NAME/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtsrealm=https://localhost:44366'

However, this is giving a response with 200 rather than a 401 redirect as expected. The event log is reporting the error:

```
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7065: There are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/ls/ to process the incoming request.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

However, this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/824303/adfs-passive-request-there-are-no-registered-protocol-handlers) suggests that if https://DOMAIN_NAME/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx works, then the simple HTTP Request should work.

In my case, the IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx page **works**, but doing the simple GET Request fails. Is there some hidden, arcane setting to get the standard WS Federation spec passive request to work?

Comment: What happens if you use the federated service name rather than domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you will get this error when the wtsrealm is setup up to a non-registered (in some way) website/resource.

Comment: this was also based on a fundamental misunderstanding of ADFS. The resource redirects to the identity provider, and doesn't control how the authentication actually happens on that end (it only trusts the identity provider gives out security tokens to those who should get them).